# numpy - stack two arrays with different types

Tags: python, numpy

SO I have two arrays

```
a=np.array([1,2,3])
b=np.array(['a','b','c'])
```

That I need to combine such that I get

```
array([1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c'])
```

I thought a simple

```
np.stack((a,b),axis=1)
```

would do it, but it turns everything into a string. How do I avoid that?

```
array([['1', 'a'],
       ['2', 'b'],
       ['3', 'c']], 
      dtype='<U21')
```

Comment: You can't all elements of `numpy` array have to be of same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put them in a structured array

```
In [104]: a=np.array([1,2,3])
     ...: b=np.array(['a','b','c'])

In [105]: arr = np.empty(a.shape[0], dtype='int,U4')
In [106]: arr
Out[106]: 
array([(0, ''), (0, ''), (0, '')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<U4')])
In [107]: arr['f0']=a
In [108]: arr['f1']=b
In [109]: arr
Out[109]: 
array([(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<U4')])
In [111]: arr['f1']
Out[111]: 
array(['a', 'b', 'c'], 
      dtype='<U4')
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html

If that isn't useful, stick with separate arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid it, since they need to be of the same type. However, you can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array(['a','b','c'])
x = np.stack((a,b),axis=1)

x[0][0].astype(np.int)
>> 1

x[0][1]
>> 'a'
```

But it's not the nicest code.